# Get model with both id and query parameters

Tags: ember-data

I have a route that should load a model (BatchDetail) and a number of related items (BatchItems). Since there are a great number of items I should be able to do pagination with the help of two request parameters, `limit` and `offset`.

Here is the route I set up:

```
App.BatchDetailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var store = this.get('store');
    var adapter = store.get('adapter');
    var id = params.batch_detail_id;

    var rejectionHandler = function(reason) {
      Ember.Logger.error(reason, reason.message);
      throw reason
    }

    return adapter.ajax("/batch_details/" + id, "GET", {
      data: { limit: 50, offset: 100 }
    }).then(function(json) {
         adapter.didFindRecord(store, App.BatchDetail, json, id);
    }).then(null, rejectionHandler);
  },


  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    return this.controllerFor('batchItems').set('model', model.get('items'));
  }
})
```

This way, when I go to `/batch_details/1` my REST adapter will fetch the correct data which I receive in `json` in the above code.

Now, the model hook should return a model object or a promise that can be resolved to a model object, and that's where the problem lies. In `setupController` (which runs after the `model` hook) model is set to `undefined` and so my code explodes.

That means that whatever `adapter.ajax` returns does not resolve correctly but instead returns `undefined`. I'm baffled, since the above mechanism is exactly how the different `find` methods in ember-data (`findById`, `findByQuery`, etc.) work and that's where I got my idea from.

Can you shed some light on what I'm not getting?

Thank you.